# Dependent parameters with Respect\Validation

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I'm making input validation in my controllers using Respect\Validation library.
I have two parameters that are optional but dependent, if the "a" parameter is present then I also need the "b" to be here and vice-versa and it is possible that there is none of them.

For now i have the following but it allow for "a" or "b" to be present.

```php
if(!Validator::keySet(Validator::key("a", Validator::intVal(), false),
                      Validator::key("b", Validator::intVal(), false))->validate($parameters)){
    //Then something is wrong
}
```

Comment: What about this rule? https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/When/

Comment: Yes it work, i didn't think to use it this way ```Validator::when(Validator::key("a"), Validator::key("b"))->validate(parameters)``` thank you very much for this !